# Replacement for standalone FedUtil to update system.IdentityModel

Tags: wif, .net-4.5, federated-identity, iis-8

i'm looking for a replacement of the Microsoft Federation Utility (FedUtil) from the WIF SDK, which allows me to automatically update (especially) the trustedIssuers list inside a web.config.
The old FedUtil could to this with /m  /u  as parameters.

Now the tool is included in VisualStudio and MS claims, there's no standalone replacement for FedUtil (refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157089.aspx).

My question is:
Do i have to do the updates manually now or is there some command or tool to update the System.IdentityModel trusted Issuers automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a tool seems not to exists which replaces FedUtils Update i made one on my own and published it to codeplex: [IdentityModel.Tools](http://identitymodeltools.codeplex.com/)