# Is there a way to run the VS 2012 extension "Identity and Access Tool" standalone

Tags: visual-studio, wif, adfs

In WIF 1.0, FedUtil was a separate exe so it could be copied to another server where you could "bind" the claims-enabled application to another instance of ADFS.

The application's web.config, federation metadata and ADFS signing certificate thumbprint would be automatically updated.

In VS 2012, the FedUtil replacement (the Identity and Access Tool) seems to be just a VS extension.

Is there a standalone / command line version?

Alternatively, is there another way to do this without having to manually update all the files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacement for standalone FedUtil to update system.IdentityModel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358528/replacement-for-standalone-fedutil-to-update-system-identitymodel)